# Editing an ImageView's pixels in place

Tags: android

I have an ImageView which has a Drawable set as its source, and whose scaleType is centerCrop. I am using this ImageView as a background in a Fragment, and I would like to set one of its corners to transparent. I've found a way of setting the corner pixels transparent (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228013/skewed-corner-of-imageview-drawable/) but the problem is that since my Drawable is scaled by the ImageView, simply changing the transparency of the pixels in the source Drawable does me no good--depending on the screen size, the cut off area is either not visible at all, or too large.

Is there a way to get the ACTUAL pixels that are being displayed in the ImageView, or would I have to calculate the Bitmap that would result from the scaling myself?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use these routines to convert your screen coordinates to bitmap coordinates:

```
 /**
     * Convert points from screen coordinates to point on image
     * @param point screen point
     * @param view ImageView
     * @return a Point on the image that corresponds to that which was touched
     */
    private Point convertPointForView(Point point, ImageView view) {
        Point outPoint = new Point();
        Matrix inverse = new Matrix();
        view.getImageMatrix().invert(inverse);
        float[] convertPoint = new float[] {point.x, point.y};
        inverse.mapPoints(convertPoint);
        outPoint.x = (int)convertPoint[0];
        outPoint.y = (int)convertPoint[1];
        return outPoint;
    }

    /**
     * Convert a rect from screen coordinates to a rect on the image
     * @param rect
     * @param view
     * @return    a rect on the image that corresponds to what is actually shown
     */
    private Rect convertRectForView(Rect rect, ImageView view) {
        Rect outRect = new Rect();
        Matrix inverse = new Matrix();
        view.getImageMatrix().invert(inverse);
        float[] convertPoints = new float[] {rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom}  ;
        inverse.mapPoints(convertPoints);
        outRect = new Rect((int)convertPoints[0], (int)convertPoints[1], (int)convertPoints[2], (int)convertPoints[3]);
        return outRect;
    }
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work for me. It looks like this works for images that are stretched, however, my scaleType is centerCrop.